# Getting bounding box of a selected region through PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, extents

Assume I have selected several features of a layer in QGIS and I would like to get the bounding information of the whole selected area through python console like the bounding of yellow regions the figure shows.

What is the easiest method to do it?

[image]

p.s. I have tried to use `layer.selectedFeatures()` but it just extract the list of selected features but cannot directly get the bounding info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is simpel in pyqgis:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() # is the currently selected layer
box = layer.boundingBoxOfSelected() # creates a bounding box
iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(box) # zooms to this bounding box
```

you could also scale the *box* variable with

```
box.scale(2,box.center()[0], box.center()[1])
```

where "2" is the scale factor.

Tested with QGIS 2.18. For further research have a look athe pyqgis api of [boundingBoxOfSelected](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsVectorLayer.html#afab88de9cef9ee231092d394372317d2)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the bounding box of every selected feature:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for feature in layer.selectedFeaturesIterator():
    print feature.geometry().boundingBox()
```